# Is it normal for MongoDB whole /data/db to be gone after a electric trip that result in crash

Tags: mongodb

I have a single machine that has MongoDB and its data is at /data/db as usual.

When my machine crashed due to an electric power trip, my MongoDB refuse to start at launch (Mac OS X Server via LaunchAgent) and also /data/db mysteriously disappear!

Also all log file are wipe out. This happen on my development SSD MBA and I thought is just a weird SSD case. But my XServe server is getting it as well when the power trip.

Am I missing some data protection articles somewhere? For sure it can't be this unreliable by just deleting /data/db!!??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not normal.

If it won't start, it's likely mongodb is indicating that you need to run a repair because mongod.lock is present and has a certain state in /data/db.  But that would mean /data/db exists.

If /data/db exists but were empty (which in this case would be bad obviously), it would start right up.

If you log(s) are missing, sounds like a more general disk issue.

So check the startup message if about mongod.lock there is data there.  Also with v1.8+ use journaling.  (albeit you wouldn't lose all datafiles even without journaling)

Comment: great answer, but I copy/paste the info below, is that all correct ? (1) mongodb has no roll-forward-log reliability… if a node goes down uncleanly for any reason you can’t trust the data on it anymore and must rebuild the node from a copy. This is a really tenuous situation to be in. A single sitewide power-outage can leave all data in an untrustworthy state. Better have good backups. (2) mongodb is a heap + b-tree, and thus is not write-optimized ...... As working-set exceeds memory-size, random write performance of mongodb will be closer to innodb/mysql.....

Comment: Yup good tip and thanks for the 1.8 info. Any explanation on why the whole /data/db can disappear. My XServe is RAID with SCSI drive I think. And they are working fine now after the power trip.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I am using Homebrew and its config file put the dbpath into another path rather than the normal /data/db

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB will never ever remove your database files!

In case of a crash you have to start mongod using the --repair option.

In addition: using the new journaling option of MongoDB in V 1.8+ that should help a lot when you run MongoDB as standalone service.

Comment: seems another mongo disaster :(

Comment: No, smells like an urban legend.

Comment: Thanks for the 1.8 version info. I am using 1.6. And no it is not an urban legend, I just encountered it and am shocked by seeing my /data/db totally gone after a power trip (a water cooler tank).

I am not here to spread anything, please :)

Comment: Sorry for making it look like urban legend. In fact I realized is my mistake. I am using Homebrew and its config file point the dbpath to a different one than /data/db